What should I do if I run into an error message, " Loading a class or package in a group"?
I updated my package updates today. Afterwards, the correct project that run perfectly now fail to run. ERROR message, " Leading a class or package in a group". What is the way to fix this?

you have { \usepackage{foo} }  and you do not want the outer braces.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/723200/1090 for example

do you have the command \spacing{1} in your preamble?

Welcome to TeX.SE.  If the answer to Ulrike's question is no, and you don't think you're loading a package in a group, then you'll need to show some code that causes the error.

Or alternatively bisect through your preamble (comment out the first half, see if error persists, if so comment out the half of the remainder, else comment out the other half, proceed until you find the offending parts of your preamble).

note that the error message should give you a line number and probably some context. if your editor doesn't show you those details, look in the .log file.
